# Generate select menu(s) from $.each json

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code and not understand WHY it not works or HOW i can get it to work.
The only thing i get in the output is the first json, so in this specific:

```
<div id="parents">
<form id="Attr">

<label class="select" for="Memory">Memory</label>
<select name="Memory" id="4"></select>

<label class="select" for="Model">Model</label>
<select name="Model" id="3"></select>

</form>
</div>
```

Generated by this function:

```
function renderAttrOptionsName(jsonData,prodID) {
    var  Attr_str = '<form id="Attr">';

    $.each(jsonData, function(index, options){
        Attr_str += '<label class="select" for="'+options.products_options_name+'">'+options.products_options_name+'</label>';
        Attr_str += '<select name="'+options.products_options_name+'" id="'+options.products_options_id+'">';

        var User = new Object();
        User.id = prodID;
        User.oid = options.products_options_id
        var userJson = JSON.stringify(User);
        $('#indicator').show();

        $.post('Controller.php',
               {
                   action: 'get_attributes_options_value',
                   user: userJson       
               },
               function(data, textStatus) {
                   $.each(data, function(index, test){
                       if (test.options_values_price == 0){
                           $( "select" ).add('<option value="' +test.products_options_values_id+ '">' +test.products_options_values_name+ '</option>');
                           //Attr_str += '<option value="' +test.products_options_values_id+ '">' +test.products_options_values_name+ '</option>'; 
                       }else{
                           $( "select" ).add('<option value="' +test.products_options_values_id+ '">' +test.products_options_values_name+ ' (' +test.price_prefix+ ' ' +test.options_values_price+ ')</option>');
                           //Attr_str += '<option value="' +test.products_options_values_id+ '">' +test.products_options_values_name+ ' (' +test.price_prefix+ ' ' +test.options_values_price+ ')</option>';
                       }
                   });
                   $('#indicator').hide();
               }, 
               "json"       
              ); 
        Attr_str += '</select>';
    });

    Attr_str += '</form">';
    $('div#parents').html(Attr_str);

}
```

The console.log shows all good.
If i do alerts in each $.each , all data is available.
I assume the DOM fails to generate the second Json data.

Comment: Please indent your code...

Comment: 1) Give the selects an ID and add to the select using a selector with that ID 2) use append instead of add - add is not the correct jQuery method to use on a select

Comment: Before i made the above, i took my working code where i use append/appendTo to generate the form.But that code was build on Websql's local storage.I want to renew my old code with current standards.It also reduces my js and have my query's outside the js.BTW if you look to the html and code you can see the selects have a ID!

Comment: @mplungjan , sorry i misunderstood you about the append, you suggested the same as Barmar.Need to figure out how to implement the selector you suggested.

Comment: I was on my phone and did not feel like writing a demo on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.append`, not `.add`.

```
var selectID = options.products_options_id;

   $.each(data, function(index, test){
       if (test.options_values_price == 0){
           $( "select#"+selectID ).append('<option value="' +test.products_options_values_id+ '">' +test.products_options_values_name+ '</option>');
           //Attr_str += '<option value="' +test.products_options_values_id+ '">' +test.products_options_values_name+ '</option>'; 
       }else{
           $( "select#"+selectID ).append('<option value="' +test.products_options_values_id+ '">' +test.products_options_values_name+ ' (' +test.price_prefix+ ' ' +test.options_values_price+ ')</option>');
           //Attr_str += '<option value="' +test.products_options_values_id+ '">' +test.products_options_values_name+ ' (' +test.price_prefix+ ' ' +test.options_values_price+ ')</option>';
       }
   });
```

`.add()` is for adding elements to a jQuery collection, not for adding to the DOM.

Comment: I'm stumbled that it partial works in this way off appending.Before i created the whole form with append and appendTo.And with partial i mean, it shows all options in both the selects.Atleast i have a dropdown now lol.

Comment: When you write `$('select')` it matches all the selects on the page. If you want to add the option to just one select, use a more specific selector, e.g. use the ID.

Comment: Yes, that one i was missing...tnX.